# Android: Handling tap event on an ImageView inside of a HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, listview, horizontalscrollview

I have a bunch of ListViews inside of a HorizontalScrollView. I would like to have a "tap" event when the user taps on the image. Currently I am using the OnTouch event but this is a problem. If I swipe the HorizontalScrollView to view more images, the OnTouch event gets fired as soon as I swipe. I really only want it to get fired when I tap on an image but not when I am swiping the actual list of images. Any idea how to do that? Thank you!

Comment: Please give some code. It's very difficult to find the problem without seeing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use onClick instead of onTouch I think.

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. I guess the wording "tap" is equivalent to "click".